# Checkout issue with virtual product

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout, downloadable, virtual-products

In `Magento 1.9.3.10` when trying to Checkout in OneStep Ajax module with downloadable (virtual) product,
after clicking the payment method one of the shipping modules gives an error and doesn't show me Order info with prices and product description:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /home/admin/domains/**/public_html/app/code/community/Balticode/Dpd/Model/Carriers/Courier/Courier.php on line 331

Line 331:

```
$quote = $request['all_items'][0]->getQuote();
```

And the whole code of the function in Courier.php:

```
    public function getShippingRateResult($_code, $request)
{

    $quote = $request['all_items'][0]->getQuote();

    $storeId = $request->getStoreId();

    if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
        $price = '0.00';
    } else {
        $price = $this->getPrice($quote, $storeId);
    }

    if ($price === false) { //Method not available for this quote
        return false;
    }

    if (Mage::helper('dpd/data')->getConfigData('classic_sallowspecific', $storeId)) { //Specific Country
        $country = explode(',', Mage::helper('dpd/data')->getConfigData('classic_specificcountry', $storeId));
        if (count($country)) {
            if (!in_array($quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId(), $country)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false; //Nothing select
        }
    }
    /** @var Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method $rate */
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    $rate->setCarrier($_code);
    $rate->setMethod($this->key);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle('DPD');
    $rate->setMethodTitle(Mage::helper('dpd/data')->getConfigData('classic_title', $storeId));
    $rate->setPrice($price);
    $rate->setCost($price);

    return $rate;
}
```

Could anybody help me with this?